Optimality of two policies versus variance of returns from a state
If for an MDP there exist two optimal policies, it may be possible that the variance of their returns are different for a given state.
This is correct, right?

Yes, optimality is defined in the expectation of a random variable, variance is not taken in consideration
Consider 2 bandits, one that has $R^1 \sim N(0, 1)$ and the second one that has $R^2 \sim N(0,100)$ ($R$ being the reward function), then any policy $\pi$ will maximize the expected reward but for sure the greedy policy that always picks the first bandit has a lower variance than the greedy one that takes every time the second bandit
